# Who can explain what means "? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;"

Tags: javascript, jquery

is part of an example of slideshow
I could not understand this part.
Who can explain me in detail:

```
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightNav')
        ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
```

how they would be able to write?(just to understand)

```
            currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightNav')
            ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
```

Comment: it is checking if the id value of the current element is equal to rightNav if yes then currentPosition variable will be equal to CurrentPosition + 1 if not equal then currentPosition will be equal to currentPosition - 1

Comment: you can read about ternary operators in php http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Robin You're linking to PHP documentation when the question is on JS? I know they do the same thing, but still...

Comment: sorry dude answered the question in hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), basically a short if.

It's equivalent is the folowing:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'rightNav') {
    currentPosition += 1;
} else {
    currentPosition -= 1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to actually give the name of the operator.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Actually that is the type of operator (i.e. it has 3 parts). The name of *that specific ternary operator* is the `conditional operator`. There just happens to only be one ternary operator in JS so the terms get misused.

Answer (score 1):

Its type of condition, it means, if condition is true, `currentPosition` will be incremented by 1, else decremented by one.

So it will be the same as:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == 'rightNav') {
  currentPosition += 1;
}
else {
  currentPosition -= 1;
}
```